# Changing electric guitar tuning heads

Tags: guitar, tuning

I have a Cort Sunset 2 electric guitar. It's a Les Paul-ish style guitar. Specs here: [www.cortguitars.com/uk/product/sunset-2](http://www.cortguitars.com/uk/product/sunset-2)

I'd like to change the tuning heads to better quality ones, preferably Grover. I have no experience of making any modifications to guitars. The current tuners look like this:

[image: tuning heads]

As you can see, there are no screws on the back of these tuners, which leads me to my questions:

1. What kind of tuning heads would be suitable for this style of guitar?
2. Do I need any special tools to remove the current ones?

Answer (score 4):

You can carefully remove one to check how they work, but I guess there is no screw because they have a raised pin on each tuner body, that goes into a small hole drilled into the back of the headstock. This pin & hole is concealed under the body of the tuner in normal use.

So you should definitely check this before buying new tuners, you might just be able to get a set with the same hole pattern.

To remove these, you need a spanner, or more neatly a hex socket, that fits the large nut on the front.  (The hex socket is just neater because you're less likely to slip and put a scratch on something!)

Also while you're looking check the hole diameter (tuner holes are usually something like 10mm diameter, though sometimes inch equivalents are used.) Ideally look for tuners that use the same hole size.

Comment: Generally the pin is in the same place - mostly :-)

Comment: if the alignment pin on the new one is far enough away from the pin on the old one, a careful mark, a punch tool and the appropriate drill bit can easily remedy alignment issues.